# PyQt5 Progress bar to fill the whole QGroupBox?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to get a progress bar to fill the whole width of a QGroupBox.

So far it looks like:

[image: progress]

I am trying to get it to go all the way across. Here is the code:

```
def progress(self):
    gBox = QGroupBox('Progress')
    progress_bar = QProgressBar(gBox)
    progress_bar.setRange(0, 1)
    # progress_bar.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 25)

    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    hbox.addWidget(progress_bar)
    hbox.addStretch(1)
    gBox.setLayout(hbox)
    return gBox
```

Do I need to stretch the QGroupBox or the QHBoxLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addStretch):

> **void QBoxLayout::addStretch(int stretch = 0)**
>
> Adds a stretchable space (a QSpacerItem) with zero minimum size and
>   stretch factor stretch to the end of this box layout.

That is, a spacer is added, that spacer is added to the end, so it pushes the widget to take the size of `sizeHint()` compressing it.

In your case you do not need it, so remove it.

```
def progress(self):
    gBox = QGroupBox('Progress')
    progress_bar = QProgressBar(gBox)
    progress_bar.setRange(0, 1)

    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    hbox.addWidget(progress_bar)
    gBox.setLayout(hbox)
    return gBox
```